# Longest paths in a graph via adjacency matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected simple graph and $A_G$ its [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). Is there an effective way to encode the information of **longest paths** of $G$ via $A_G$? (Or maybe using some kind of [Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix)?)

> For example, to encode the information of the diameter $d(G)$ of $G$, one can define
>   \begin{align} f_n : L\left(\mathbb{R}^{|V|},\mathbb{R}^{|V|}\right)&\to L\left(\mathbb{R}^{|V|},\mathbb{R}^{|V|}\right) \\ T\quad &\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^n T^k\end{align}
>   and verify that $d(G) = \min\{n: \left(f_n(A_G)\right)_{ij}> 0,~\forall ij\}$, that is, the least $n$ such that you can guarantee that every node has reached every other node. The eccentricity $e(v_i)$ of a node can be obtained in the same way, but this time you look only to the $i$th column of $f_n(A_G)$.

Maybe it's not the most efficient way to obtain $d(G)$ from $A_G$, but I think it captures the idea of what I'm asking.

Comment: Interesting! There may or may not be a way to encode the information of longest paths via the adjacency matrix or the Laplacian. However, it will not be easily computable, since [the longest path problem is NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). Here's what so difficult about it (you probably already realised this): in the powers of $A_G$, you find the number of walks from $i$ to $j$, but there is no easy way to see which of these walks are simple.